# Dynamic Listview with EditText not clear values in Same Activity

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have used **`ExpandebleListView`** in my code , Rows are dynamically generated on **ADD `Button`** click. Each New Row contain two **`EditText`**.

Now when i click on **Clear `Button`**, it clear `list` items, but when i click on add new item, its **showing new with last inputed value inside `EditText`**.

So, How to clear all contents and items Without changing activity on `Button` `Click` ?

Here's My code for clear Data

```
  itemBean.clear();
  ItemBean objBean = new ItemBean();
  objBean.Qty = "";
  objBean.Rate = "";
  objBean.Total = "";
  itemBean.add(objBean);
  listviewAdapterForItem.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here's My code for Add Data

```
 ItemBean objBean = new ItemBean();
  objBean.Qty = "";
  objBean.Rate = "";
  objBean.Total = "";
  itemBean.add(objBean);
  listviewAdapterForItem.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here's My code for Adapter

```
public class ListviewAdapterForItem extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<ItemBean> bean;

public ListviewAdapterForItem(Context context, ArrayList<ItemBean> itemBeans) {
    this.context = context;
    if(this.bean != null){
        this.bean.clear();
    }
    this.bean = itemBeans;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return bean.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return bean.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_items,null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.editQty = convertView.findViewById(R.id.editQty);
        viewHolder.editRate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.editRate);
        viewHolder.txtRs = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtRs);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    ItemBean objBean = (ItemBean) getItem(position);
    if(objBean != null) {
        viewHolder.editQty.setText(objBean.getQty());
        viewHolder.editRate.setText(objBean.getRate());
        viewHolder.txtRs.setText(objBean.getTotal());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: please ad adapter class  code to question

Comment: Hi @sukhbir , I have posted my Adapter code also

Comment: From code its looks like you are not using `ExpendableListView`. Where is clear button and add button clicks?

Comment: Clear Button And Add Button Click inside Activity Code. And I have posted clear button code already

Comment: please add activity code. it will help to clarify issue.

Comment: i have posted both ADD and Clear Button code

Comment: Please see soluton in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some logical mistakes in your code I think, firstly for clear

```
bean.clear();
ItemBean objBean = new ItemBean();
objBean.Qty = "";
objBean.Rate = "";
objBean.Total = "";
bean.add(objBean);
listviewAdapterForItem.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And for adding because **bean** is your list of items

```
  ItemBean objBean = new ItemBean();
  objBean.Qty = "abc";   // some dummy values to test
  objBean.Rate = "xyz";
  objBean.Total = "abc";
  bean.add(objBean);
  listviewAdapterForItem.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If you want to clear all the items, then you should do it like

```
bean.clear(); // it will clear all your list, what you are doing is clearing or removing one item
```

Well in your `getView()` function get the reference for the edit text and clear it there

```
viewHolder.editQty= (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exitText);// change editext accordingly
editText.getText().clear();
```

**Or** other solution can be declare some xyz variable typed `String` initialize it as an empty like `String xyz = ""` and then

```
editText.setText(xyz);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178342/discussion-between-abdul-kawee-and-umesh-devani).

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting any value to your `Editext` You should do this following in your on `getView()`

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_items,null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.editQty = convertView.findViewById(R.id.editQty);
            viewHolder.editRate = convertView.findViewById(R.id.editRate);
            viewHolder.txtRs = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtRs);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        String Qty =bean.get(position).Qty;
        viewHolder.editQty.setText(Qty);
        viewHolder.editQty.addTextChangedListener(new onEditTextchange(holder.editQty, position));
    }



public class onEditTextchange implements TextWatcher {


        EditText getvalue;
        int pos;

        public onEditTextchange(EditText getvalue, int position) {
            this.getvalue = getvalue;
            this.pos = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            ItemBean objBean = new ItemBean();
            objBean.Qty = getvalue.getText().toString();
            objBean.Rate = items.get(pos).question;
            objBean.Total = items.get(pos).question_id;
            bean.set(pos, objBean);
        }
    }
```

**Hope this will help**

Comment: Same problem , List clear with contents but when add new it also clear complete list

Comment: you are not adding any value to  class variables. Please add some value in varraibles like  `objBean.Qty = "2 kg ";` while adding value to `Array list`.

Comment: did you check ?

Comment: I am already adding empty string to my class variable, you can check it on add button click. Because user will input in both EditText, so there is blank value at add time

Comment: Basically you have to  reatin value in you `ArrayList` .. what ever you instering in your `Edittext` should be updated in your  `Arraylist` according to the position. so that it can retain value.

Comment: Please see update amswer to retain value inside `beanList`

Comment: Hi did you found any soloution?

Comment: No, i didn't found any solution yet, why do you down vote question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178340/discussion-between-sukhbir-and-umesh-devani).